# how to reload the UIpicker view data

Tags: iphone, widget, uipickerview, reload

I want to reload the data in the UIpicker view. actaully i have 2 picker on the view. and i want to fill the data in the second picker according to the previous selected picker value. is it possible? please suggest how i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about looking at:

http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006842-CH3-SW10

in response to the didSelectRow message your view controller is sent as the UIPickerView delegate?